# Filter a few computers before exporting from pipeline

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to filter out 4 machines prior to exporting to a csv file.  I have no clue how to filter them out.  I tried the IF clause but this produced nothing.  Please help.

```
$old = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90) # Modify the -90 to match your threshold 
$oldComputers = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=Workstations,DC=Corporate,DC=Local" -SearchScope 2 -Filter { PasswordLastSet -le $old } -Properties *
$oldComputers

if ($_.name -notlike "1919DD" -or $_.name -notlike "1919SMAHESHWARE" -or $_.name -notlike "1919IETEST" -or $_.name -notlike "1920BPASCERITB") {
    Export-Csv c:\temp\Over90DaysMachines.csv -NoTypeInformation -Force -Append
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, to be able to use the current object variable (`$_`) you need a pipeline context. Simply putting an `if` statement after echoing a variable doesn't automagically feed the echoed value(s) into the `if` statement. You need to change this:

```
$oldComputers

if ($_.Name -notlike "1919DD" -or ...) {
    Export-Csv c:\temp\Over90DaysMachines.csv -NoTypeInformation -Force -Append
}
```

into something like this:

```
$oldComputers | Where-Object {
    $_.Name -notlike "1919DD" -or ...
} | Export-Csv c:\temp\Over90DaysMachines.csv -NoType -Force
```

However, even with that change your filter won't work correctly, because you connected the `-notlike` clauses via `-or` when you should have used `-and`. You obviously meant to process objects only if their name doesn't match any of the given values. But for your logical expression to evaluate to `$false` the name would have to match *all* of the reference value *at the same time*. Which clearly isn't possible, thus your expression always evaluates to `$true`.

**Example:**

Assume that you have a variable `$v` that should not be equal to either `A`, `B`, or `C`. Applying your logic, the expression would look somewhat like this in PowerShell:

```
($v -notlike 'A') -or ($v -notlike 'B') -or ($v -notlike 'C')
```

If `$v` takes for instance the value `A` that expression becomes

```
  ('A' -notlike 'A') -or ('A' -notlike 'B') -or ('A' -notlike 'C')
⇔ ($false) -or ($true) -or ($true)
⇔ $true
```

To check if a give value equals neither of the reference values you need to connect the clauses via `-and`:

```
  ('A' -notlike 'A') -and ('A' -notlike 'B') -and ('A' -notlike 'C')
⇔ ($false) -and ($true) -and ($true)
⇔ $false
```

```
$oldComputers | Where-Object {
    $_.Name -notlike "1919DD" -and
    $_.Name -notlike "1919SMAHESHWARE" -and
    $_.Name -notlike "1919IETEST" -and
    $_.Name -notlike "1920BPASCERITB"
} | Export-Csv c:\temp\Over90DaysMachines.csv -NoType -Force
```

Note BTW, that the `-notlike` operator behaves exactly like the `-ne` operator when the reference string doesn't contain wildcard characters. If you're not doing fuzzy matches anyway you could simplify your expression by checking if the given name is (not) found in an array of names instead of doing multiple checks for (in)equality:

```
$excludes = '1919DD', '1919SMAHESHWARE', '1919IETEST', '1920BPASCERITB'
$oldComputers | Where-Object {
    $excludes -notcontains $_.Name
} | Export-Csv c:\temp\Over90DaysMachines.csv -NoType -Force
```

Another option would be a regular expression (non-)match:

```
$oldComputers | Where-Object {
    $_.Name -notmatch '^1919DD|1919SMAHESHWARE|1919IETEST|1920BPASCERITB$'
} | Export-Csv c:\temp\Over90DaysMachines.csv -NoType -Force
```

Comment: as usual, you not only provide the solution, but school me every time so it actually makes perfect sense.. thanks bud.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the code in the OP is a fragment from a larger script. Presumably it is the body or part of the body of a `ForEach-Object`. (If not then `$_` doesn't make sense in this context). However a `ForEach-Object` isn't necessary. You can filter out the unwanted computers as follows:

```
$old = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90) # Modify the -90 to match your threshold 
$oldComputers = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=Workstations,DC=Corporate,DC=Local" -SearchScope 2 -Filter { PasswordLastSet -le $old } -Properties *
$oldComputers | Where-Object {
    $_.name -notin "1919SMAHESHWARE","1919IETEST", "1920BPASCERITB"
} | Export-Csv c:\temp\Over90DaysMachines.csv -NoTypeInformation -Force -Append
```

This assumes that `$oldComputers` is an array of object where each object has a property `name` and the value of `name` is a string like "server1", "server2", etc. The script in the OP outputs `$oldComputers` so verify it looks like a set of objects, with a `name` property consisting of a string where the servers to be excluded are spelled exactly as listed in the OP.

Comment: It should be noted that `-notin` requires PowerShell v3 or newer.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks. @Hiten004 If PS 2.0 is being used, then then the order of the operands can be reversed and -notcontains can be used instead. `"1919SMAHESHWARE","1919IETEST", "1920BPASCERITB" -notcontains $_.name`

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
$old = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90) # Modify the -90 to match your threshold 
$oldComputers = Get-ADComputer -searchbase "OU=Workstations,DC=Corporate,DC=Local" -SearchScope 2 -Filter { PasswordLastSet -le $old } -Properties * 

    $oldComputers = $oldComputers | where {$_.name -notlike "1919DD" 
    ` -or $_.name -notlike "1919SMAHESHWARE" 
    ` -or $_.name -notlike "1919IETEST" 
    ` -or $_.name -notlike "1920BPASCERITB"}

Export-Csv c:\temp\Over90DaysMachines.csv -NoTypeInformation -force -append
```

Comment: It did not work @Hiten I get this continuous error : -or : The term '-or' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:6 char:6
+      -or $_.name -notlike "1919IETEST"
+      ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-or:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Try `$oldComputers = $oldComputers | where {$_.name -notlike "1919DD" -or $_.name -notlike "1919SMAHESHWARE" -or $_.name -notlike "1919IETEST" -or $_.name -notlike "1920BPASCERITB"}` on the same line or use backticks ` to break lines